# Custom configure parameters for yum install php

Tags: php, centos, yum

I use yum as my package manager on CentOS, running as a testing web server. I want to re-configure PHP with `--with-mysqli=mysqlnd`, but do it through yum. Is this possible, and if so, how?

At the moment, mysqli is already installed, but uses the default libmysql.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CentOS has left out MySQLND of their build. You have to find some third party repository  where php5-mysqlnd is compiled. For example [Remis one](http://blog.famillecollet.com/post/2009/11/14/PHP-5.3,-zts-and-mysqlnd)